# Programming with verbose option in C

Tags: c

Does someone know how to write a program in C with the verbose option (the option to choose if messages are printed or not) in a nice way.

I mean, not writing an if(verbose) for each printf in the code.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a (variadic) macro / vararg function that tests a flag before calling something like vfprintf.

```
/* Crude example. */
void my_log(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    if (!ok_to_log)
        return;

    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

#### EDIT As requested

How about a slightly modified [gnu example](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

```
#define eprintf(format, ...) do {                 \
    if (ok_to_print)                              \
        fprintf(stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);   \
} while(0)
```

Comment: @Kits Don't forget about [macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)!

Comment: But then how should I #define the macro?

Answer (score 4):

Make an array of function pointers

```
print_function_type fx[2] = {quietprint, verboseprint};
```

and instead of using an if when printing, use the correct element of the array

```
// if verbosemode is 0 call quietprint
// if verbosemode is 1 call verboseprint
fx[verbosemode]("%d", foo);
```

Comment: May be a mix of this and @cnicutar solution will do because I need the print instruction to be with a number of arguments variable and the arguments of different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own printf-like function that checks for the verbose flag and then calls printf, if necessary.

Comment: Yes, but that is not easy - you would need your function to accept variable number of parameters for the internal printf...

Comment: That's not difficult.  Use vprintf internally.